# What does "If a zero is present in the crosstabulation, no association can be assessed." mean?

Tags: ordinal-data, categorical-data, association-measure

On this [website](http://www.statisticssolutions.com/nominal-variable-association/), I found that one of the assumptions for nominal association measures tests (such as Cramer's V) is that "If a zero is present in the crosstabulation, no association can be assessed."(scroll to bottom to see assumptions in the above link). I thought at first that this meant that if there are "0" values in the crosstabulation, you can't do the test. But then I read somewhere else that values that have null values will be ignored in some other test (can't remember if it was nominal or ordinal association tests). Is this what the writer in the link above meant? Not that you can't do the test but that any null values will be ignored when you do the analysis?

I found something similar for another [guideline](https://www.statisticssolutions.com/ordinal-association/) from the same website about ordinal measures of association c. At the bottom it says the same quote that I mentioned above. Can someone clarify this statement for me?

Comment: I believe this is not the first time you have found vague, unreliable, misleading, or wrong information on that site.  Isn't it time you used a better statistical resource?

Comment: Thanks but the problem is that when I try to search for "Assumptions of xx test", I can't really find any sites that can give me an answer I can understand as I'm still new to statistics. Would you please help me answer my above question? Or do you have any comments or suggestions to make about it? I'm really urgently needing answers. Thanks.

Comment: Please see https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=contingency+zero.